# list[I] becomes a list instead of an item

Tags: python, list, boolean, extract

I am a high school student doing a simple merge sort algorithm, but I encountered below error message. Help is much appreciated!

> File "main.py", line 22, in mergesort
> if l_list[i] <= r_list[j]:

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

Here's my code:

```
list = [1, 3, 5, 6, 2]

def mergesort(list):
    n = len(list)

    if n <= 1:
      return

    mid_cut = n // 2
    l_list = list[:mid_cut]
    r_list = list[mid_cut:]
    mergesort(l_list)
    mergesort(r_list)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    list.clear()

    while i < len(l_list) and j < len(r_list):
      if l_list[i] <= r_list[j]:
        list.append(l_list[i])
        i += 1
      else:
        list.append(r_list[j])
        j += 1

    if i < len(l_list):
      list.append(l_list[i:])
    else:
      list.append(r_list[j:])

mergesort(list)
```

I tried extracting items from two local lists and compare them, but one of the "item" turned into a list somehow.

Comment: Note: it is discouraged in Python to use popular builtin functions as variable names since it masks these functions causing errors that are difficult to detect in larger code bases.  Thus, names such as list, str, etc.  are discouraged.  Simple alternative in this case is to use list_.

Comment: All that for a sort?  What happened to `list.sort()`?  Also note that you are overriding a keyword `list` by assigning values to it.  You probably need a new name for that variable

Comment: Asking me to change variable name "list" is a great advice, I will keep in mind in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, you append slices to list.

```
if i < len(l_list):
    list.append(l_list[i:])
else:
    list.append(r_list[j:])
```

Use list.extend(...) instead:

```
if i < len(l_list):
    list.extend(l_list[i:])
else:
    list.extend(r_list[j:])
```

Comment: You are right, this fixed my code. Never would have figured this out from the error message. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

list is reserved word in python, name it something other than list it may be conflicting with your code.

Have a look at this.

```
def mergeSort(array):
        if len(array) > 1:
    
            #  r is the point where the array is divided into two subarrays
            r = len(array)//2
            L = array[:r]
            M = array[r:]
    
            # Sort the two halves
            mergeSort(L)
            mergeSort(M)
    
            i = j = k = 0
    
            # Until we reach either end of either L or M, pick larger among
            # elements L and M and place them in the correct position at A[p..r]
            while i < len(L) and j < len(M):
                if L[i] < M[j]:
                    array[k] = L[i]
                    i += 1
                else:
                    array[k] = M[j]
                    j += 1
                k += 1
    
            # When we run out of elements in either L or M,
            # pick up the remaining elements and put in A[p..r]
            while i < len(L):
                array[k] = L[i]
                i += 1
                k += 1
    
            while j < len(M):
                array[k] = M[j]
                j += 1
                k += 1
    
    
    # Print the array
    def printList(array):
        for i in range(len(array)):
            print(array[i], end=" ")
        print()
    
    
    # Driver program
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        array = [6, 5, 12, 10, 9, 1]
    
        mergeSort(array)
    
        print("Sorted array is: ")
        printList(array)
```

Comment: Not the problem for this code but great advice nevertheless, I just changed all "list" to "list_"